# Тайлинг из текстурного атласа openGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl, opengles

Подскажите пожалуйста вообще тайлинг части текстуры в openGL возможен ?

Просто наложить текстуру через uv координаты понятно как, но она на большие полигоны растянется некрасиво.

Понятно как сделать тайлинг из целой текстуры - просто ставим GLES20.GL_REPEAT.

А хотелось бы упаковать текстуры в один атлас и взять сделать тайлинг кусочка аталаса (например выделенный красным).
[image: текстурный атлас]

Comment: Скажите, удалось ли добиться нужного результата и как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общих чертах, можно на шейдере.

Передаем:

1. Передаем UV координаты тайла (обведенного красным, `u1, u2, v1, v2`)

В шейдере:

1. Получаем UV положение фрагмента (пикселя) (`pu, pv`)
2. Переводим это в UV атласа со смещением и по модулю ширины тайла в атласе
3. Сэмплим текстуру из полученной точки

Формула приведения (не проверял), что-то типа:

```
tu = u1 + (pu) % (u2 - u1);
```